# Should I have posted at CodeReview instead?

Tags: discussion, migration

The dba thread in question: [Access (Jet) SQL: DateTime stamps in TableB flanking each DateTime stamp in TableA](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/116552/access-jet-sql-datetime-stamps-in-tableb-flanking-each-datetime-stamp-in-tabl)

I believe with the status of my code as it now stands, my question may be better suited for CR than it is for DBA. Should I request that it be migrated? Should I cross-post this meta question over on meta.CR (but obviously not cross-post the base question itself on CR proper)?

When I initially asked my question yesterday, my base code was not fully developed and had a couple of minor bugs, which "disqualified" it from consideration over at CR. I believe those have since been addressed (but I defer to your better judgement).

mpag a.k.a. today's StackExchange newbie

Relevant topics that addressed this generally, but not my case specifically:

1. [Which site is best for code reviews of queries?](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1317/which-site-is-best-for-code-reviews-of-queries)
2. [Overlap between codereview and dba](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/187/overlap-between-codereview-and-dba/188)
3. [Recommendation: Beginner needs to Regularly Post SQL Code for Troubleshooting. Where to?](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1283/recommendation-beginner-needs-to-regularly-post-sql-code-for-troubleshooting-w)
4. [Is MS Access on-topic?](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6/is-ms-access-on-topic)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your question is on-topic here and would also be [on-topic for Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) (I checked with a moderator from that site to be sure).

We do not have many active Access experts here on dba.se, so a high proportion of questions unfortunately [currently go unanswered](https://dba.stackexchange.com/tags/ms-access/topusers). Code Review has a [much better record](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tags/ms-access/topusers) in that respect, but that may simply reflect the low number of Access questions there (22).

Even so, on balance, I suggest you leave this question where it is for a couple of days at least. If it still has a low number of views and no answers after that time, we can look at migrating* it, or other ways to attract attention.

The question would benefit from including table and index definitions wherever it ends up. Also, be sure to add clarifications to the question body rather than in comments.

<sub>* If we do migrate it, we will almost certainly [close/delete it here.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu)</sub>

Answer (score 8):

Your question would be on-topic on Code Review.  However, it is also on-topic for DBA.  [By Stack Exchange policy](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/251568/148099), being a better fit on another site does not make it eligible for migration; only questions that are off-topic on the original site may be migrated.  (Many questions are asked every day that could conceivably fit on more than one site.  That rule exists for a good reason.)

If you don't get a satisfactory answer here after waiting a reasonable amount of time, you are welcome to cross-post your question.  Be sure to declare your cross-post with mutual links as comments, to avoid wasting other people's time.

---

In my experience answering questions on Code Review, I've found reviews of complex SQL queries to be some of the most time-consuming questions.  You really have to understand every part of the query before you even begin to formulate a response, and in many cases it is necessary to rewrite the monster query from scratch using a completely different strategy.  ([Example 1](//codereview.stackexchange.com/a/54243/9357), [2](//codereview.stackexchange.com/a/29833/9357))  You can make your question more attractive by making it as easy as possible to review your code.

- Provide the table definitions of all relations involved, so that reviewers don't have to derive them by reverse-engineering your query.
- Mention all constraints, keys, and indexes.
- Provide sample data and the expected result set.
- Include an executable demo as an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com).  I realize that SQL Fiddle doesn't support MS Access, but it looks like another database like MySQL could be a close enough substitute for demonstration purposes.

Comment: I provided an English explanation of the keys, but I can definitely see how my question would be aided by at least a pseudo-coded list of keys, foreign key constraints and indexes. Thank you for suggesting the fiddle method as well.

Comment: added table defs to the post (and rearranged it)

Comment: I was thinking of posting on CodeReview's meta page to raise attention. However a) I don't have the rep to post on the meta there b) I don't want to make a "question" on the main CR page, as this thread already has enough momentum to keep it. If you believe it appropriate, could you post a "question" on the meta there and reference the bounty here? :)

Comment: I've [publicized it already](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/24483538#24483538) in our chat room.  I'll do it again now.